# Javascript - Timeout Threads

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, settimeout

I would like to know if there is a possible implementation for the following problem in JavaScript:

I want to develop a web application that monitors inactivity for several incoming connections. 10 or more clients would connect to the web app (via WebSockets) causing a 2min timeout timer to start. If a client doesnt make contact with the app for the above internal, its gonna marked as "inactive".

In a more "traditional" language I would've solved the above situation with several threads (one for each client), which would start and fire the timeout timers.

But as far as I can tell JavaScript is single-threaded, so I have no clue where to start..

Comment: FWIW, (and you don't mind jQuery for the sake of example): http://jsfiddle.net/hV9r2/ -- In this I start with 10 "workers" with a 10 second timeout. I use the jsFildde AJAX api and make "randomly-intervalled" calls (anywhere from 0-12 seconds). those with 11 & 12 seconds should "timeout". You can see (through the table) that they all inevitably time-out, it's just a matter of odds and pulling a timeout > 10 the "next" time.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this great sample. I'll try to study a bit more on workers and check out the possible implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is run client side, so each user would be running the JS locally.

**Edit:** Jason pointed out in the comments that I missed the Node.js tag you put on the article; thus the above statement is not true for Node.js.

I understand your question to be "How can I have a 2 minute idle check written in JS?".  Personally, I'd have a global in your JS code which keeps track of the last time the user performed an action.  At the end of each JS function have this variable set with the current Time ([More Info Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)).  Next, use a JS interval to check that value periodically ([More Info Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)).

You would end up with something like this:

```
var myTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeout = 2 * 60 * 1000;
var interval = 30 * 1000;
window.setInterval(checkTimeout(),interval);

function checkTimeout() {
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    t = t-myTime;
    if (t >= timeout) {
        alert("You've been Idle for 5s+");
    }
    window.setInterval(checkTimeout(),interval);
}
function setTime() {
    myTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZFGZ/3/) is an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: LePhleg is using node.js, which is server side.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and sorry for the delay. I find this constantly-checking approach somewhat consuming, but as I can see the other answers suggested something similar for JS.

Comment: @LePhleg, glad it was helpful. As for resource consumption, the best suggestion I have is that you only have one of these running at a time (check all users in the same function); even then that's based on speculation as I do not know how efficient the setInterval function is.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for your connections, e.g.:

```
var connections = [{id: 1, lastActive: ...,}, ...];
```

Then, use the `setTimeout` function to check on these periodically:

```
var interval = 10000; // 10 seconds in milliseconds
var expireTime = 1000 * 60 * 2 // 2 minutes in milliseconds
setTimeout(function() {
  now = new Date()
  for(i = 0; i < connections.length; ++i) {
    if(now - connections[i]['lastActive'] > expireTime) {
      // Do something to make this connection inactive.
    }
  }
}, interval);
```